# How do I tell Windows Update to not check for updates for my GPU drivers?

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, windows-update, gpu

Windows 8.1 at work (no group policies) wants me to update my GPU drivers through Windows Update (it appears in my optional updates list). I'd rather do this manually since it gives me more control over what exactly is installed. Is there a way to tell Windows Update (the desktop version, not the Modern UI version) to not check for GPU driver updates?

My GPU is an AMD Radeon 7500-7600M series.

The official name for the update is "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. - Graphics Adapter WDDM1.3 - AMD Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series" and It's been released in July,2014.

screenshot of the update:

[image]

Comment: In update center right click on Update -> Update hide.

Comment: Have you installed CCC (Catalyst Control Center) - here you can set "Check for update" or not

Comment: @Watsche I'm looking for a more permanent solution. AFAIK, that will make it keep appearing again when a new version arrives.

Comment: If you have a digitally signed AMD/Nvidia driver WIndows Update shouldn't be installing the generic display driver

Comment: The official name for the update is "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. - Graphics Adapter WDDM1.3 - AMD Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series" and It's been released in July,2014.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a permanent solution, only short-term workarounds. For example you can change the Windows Update settings to **Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them**, hiding driver updates when needed (as suggested by Watsche). Or you can install a newer driver version yourself. Related questions (currently without useful answers): [How can I stop Windows 8 from installing nVidia software?](http://superuser.com/q/549311/289138), [Preventing Windows Update from updating a certain driver via command line/script?](http://superuser.com/q/651888/289138)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I know of is a bit of killing a fly with a cannon. You will need to get a server edition of windows on your network and install the [Windows Server Update Services (WSUS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_Update_Services). What this does is allow you to have fine grained control of what updates are presented/installed to each computer on the network that uses the server as its update server (the server can be set by local settings or via GPOs).

It won't give you fine enough grained control to only stop GPU drivers, but you can turn off all driver updates but leaving on the rest of the updates you would get through the windows update system.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to is to hit the windows key+q and go to "change device installation settings" and tell windows to not search for driver updates.

Comment: That option is already disabled.